# Post JSON missing parameters

Tags: php, restler

got a class which has a post function which should store a large amaount of parameters to db.
The problem is, that i can´t get the send parameters from request body. I tested nearly every combination:

- add request_data as end parameter -> not working (if i drop it it says ZEITSTEMPEL missing)
- set parameters without NULL (required) -> not working
- just take two paramters (thought it were too much) -> not working
- tried to get param by $request_data['ZEITSTEMPEL'] -> not working (shows null)

I tried all this with newest version (today) of restler and posting through restler api
and restcliebt (firefox addon).

Firefox-addon throughs additional error i can´t solve (added content type json wont work)

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Forbidden: Content type application/JSON is not supported."
    }
}
```

I´m a bit stucked on this hope one could help.
Here´s my code:

```
class messprotokoll {

    /**
     * save messprotokoll
     *
     * one could save a messprotokoll
     * result is the status
     * in JSON format
     *
     *
     * @param string $ZEITSTEMPEL {@from body} comment
     * @param string $ID_MESSPROTOKOLL {@from body} comment
     * @param string $ID_GERAET {@from body} comment
     * @param string $D_229 {@from body} comment
     * @param string $D_230 {@from body} comment
     * @param string $TYP {@from body} comment
     * ....continues...
     * @throws 400 No value given for id
     * @return json
     *
     */
    function post($ZEITSTEMPEL=NULL,$ID_MESSPROTOKOLL=NULL,$ID_GERAET=NULL,$D_229=NULL,$D_230=NULL,$TYP=NULL,$D_226=NULL,$D_227=NULL,$D_228=NULL,$D_223=NULL,$D_224=NULL,$D_225=NULL,$D_220=NULL,$D_221=NULL,$D_222=NULL,$D_217=NULL,$D_218=NULL,$D_219=NULL,$D_214=NULL,$D_215=NULL,$D_216=NULL,$D_211=NULL,$D_212=NULL,$D_213=NULL,$D_208=NULL,$D_209=NULL,$D_210=NULL,$D_205=NULL,$D_206=NULL,$D_207=NULL,$D_202=NULL,$D_203=NULL,$D_204=NULL,$D_199=NULL,$D_200=NULL,$D_201=NULL,$D_196=NULL,$D_197=NULL,$D_198=NULL,$D_193=NULL,$D_194=NULL,$D_195=NULL,$D_190=NULL,$D_191=NULL,$D_192=NULL,$D_187=NULL,$D_188=NULL,$D_189=NULL,$D_184=NULL,$D_185=NULL,$D_186=NULL,$D_181=NULL,$D_182=NULL,$D_183=NULL,$D_178=NULL,$D_179=NULL,$D_180=NULL,$D_175=NULL,$D_176=NULL,$D_177=NULL,$D_172=NULL,$D_173=NULL,$D_174=NULL,$D_169=NULL,$D_170=NULL,$D_171=NULL,$D_166=NULL,$D_167=NULL,$D_168=NULL,$D_163=NULL,$D_164=NULL,$D_165=NULL,$D_160=NULL,$D_161=NULL,$D_162=NULL,$D_157=NULL,$D_158=NULL,$D_159=NULL,$D_154=NULL,$D_155=NULL,$D_156=NULL,$D_151=NULL,$D_152=NULL,$D_153=NULL,$D_148=NULL,$D_149=NULL,$D_150=NULL,$D_145=NULL,$D_146=NULL,$D_147=NULL,$D_142=NULL,$D_143=NULL,$D_144=NULL,$D_139=NULL,$D_140=NULL,$D_141=NULL,$D_136=NULL,$D_137=NULL,$D_138=NULL,$D_133=NULL,$D_134=NULL,$D_135=NULL,$D_130=NULL,$D_131=NULL,$D_132=NULL,$D_127=NULL,$D_128=NULL,$D_129=NULL,$D_124=NULL,$D_125=NULL,$D_126=NULL,$D_121=NULL,$D_122=NULL,$D_123=NULL,$D_118=NULL,$D_119=NULL,$D_120=NULL,$D_115=NULL,$D_116=NULL,$D_117=NULL,$D_112=NULL,$D_113=NULL,$D_114=NULL,$D_109=NULL,$D_110=NULL,$D_111=NULL,$D_106=NULL,$D_107=NULL,$D_108=NULL,$D_103=NULL,$D_104=NULL,$D_105=NULL,$D_100=NULL,$D_101=NULL,$D_102=NULL,$D_097=NULL,$D_098=NULL,$D_099=NULL,$D_094=NULL,$D_095=NULL,$D_096=NULL,$D_091=NULL,$D_092=NULL,$D_093=NULL,$D_088=NULL,$D_089=NULL,$D_090=NULL,$D_085=NULL,$D_086=NULL,$D_087=NULL,$D_082=NULL,$D_083=NULL,$D_084=NULL,$D_079=NULL,$D_080=NULL,$D_081=NULL,$D_076=NULL,$D_077=NULL,$D_078=NULL,$D_073=NULL,$D_074=NULL,$D_075=NULL,$D_070=NULL,$D_071=NULL,$D_072=NULL,$D_067=NULL,$D_068=NULL,$D_069=NULL,$D_064=NULL,$D_065=NULL,$D_066=NULL,$D_061=NULL,$D_062=NULL,$D_063=NULL,$D_058=NULL,$D_059=NULL,$D_060=NULL,$D_055=NULL,$D_056=NULL,$D_057=NULL,$D_052=NULL,$D_053=NULL,$D_054=NULL,$D_049=NULL,$D_050=NULL,$D_051=NULL,$D_046=NULL,$D_047=NULL,$D_048=NULL,$D_043=NULL,$D_044=NULL,$D_045=NULL,$D_040=NULL,$D_041=NULL,$D_042=NULL,$D_037=NULL,$D_038=NULL,$D_039=NULL,$D_034=NULL,$D_035=NULL,$D_036=NULL,$D_031=NULL,$D_032=NULL,$D_033=NULL,$D_028=NULL,$D_029=NULL,$D_030=NULL,$D_025=NULL,$D_026=NULL,$D_027=NULL,$D_022=NULL,$D_023=NULL,$D_024=NULL,$D_019=NULL,$D_020=NULL,$D_021=NULL,$D_016=NULL,$D_017=NULL,$D_018=NULL,$D_013=NULL,$D_014=NULL,$D_015=NULL,$D_010=NULL,$D_011=NULL,$D_012=NULL,$D_007=NULL,$D_008=NULL,$D_009=NULL,$D_004=NULL,$D_005=NULL,$D_006=NULL,$D_001=NULL,$D_002=NULL,$D_003=NULL,$PROTOKOLLNR=NULL,$GERAETENR=NULL,$PRUEFER=NULL,$UEBERTRAGUNGSDATEN=NULL,$ID_GERAET2=NULL,$ID_GERAET3=NULL,$ID_GERAET4=NULL,$GERAETENR2=NULL,$GERAETENR3=NULL,$GERAETENR4=NULL,$Bemerkungen=NULL,$Durchgefuehrte_Arbeiten=NULL,$ID_Techniker=NULL,$request_data=NULL) {

        //function post($ID_MESSPROTOKOLL,$ZEITSTEMPEL=NULL){
        echo "Request:".$request_data['ZEITSTEMPEL']; //this is NULL??
        $sql= "INSERT INTO dbo.MESSPROTOKOLL(ZEITSTEMPEL,ID_MESSPROTOKOLL,ID_GERAET,D_229,D_230,TYP,D_226,D_227,D_228,D_223,D_224,D_225,D_220,D_221,D_222,D_217,D_218,D_219,D_214,D_215,D_216,D_211,D_212,D_213,D_208,D_209,D_210,D_205,D_206,D_207,D_202,D_203,D_204,D_199,D_200,D_201,D_196,D_197,D_198,D_193,D_194,D_195,D_190,D_191,D_192,D_187,D_188,D_189,D_184,D_185,D_186,D_181,D_182,D_183,D_178,D_179,D_180,D_175,D_176,D_177,D_172,D_173,D_174,D_169,D_170,D_171,D_166,D_167,D_168,D_163,D_164,D_165,D_160,D_161,D_162,D_157,D_158,D_159,D_154,D_155,D_156,D_151,D_152,D_153,D_148,D_149,D_150,D_145,D_146,D_147,D_142,D_143,D_144,D_139,D_140,D_141,D_136,D_137,D_138,D_133,D_134,D_135,D_130,D_131,D_132,D_127,D_128,D_129,D_124,D_125,D_126,D_121,D_122,D_123,D_118,D_119,D_120,D_115,D_116,D_117,D_112,D_113,D_114,D_109,D_110,D_111,D_106,D_107,D_108,D_103,D_104,D_105,D_100,D_101,D_102,D_097,D_098,D_099,D_094,D_095,D_096,D_091,D_092,D_093,D_088,D_089,D_090,D_085,D_086,D_087,D_082,D_083,D_084,D_079,D_080,D_081,D_076,D_077,D_078,D_073,D_074,D_075,D_070,D_071,D_072,D_067,D_068,D_069,D_064,D_065,D_066,D_061,D_062,D_063,D_058,D_059,D_060,D_055,D_056,D_057,D_052,D_053,D_054,D_049,D_050,D_051,D_046,D_047,D_048,D_043,D_044,D_045,D_040,D_041,D_042,D_037,D_038,D_039,D_034,D_035,D_036,D_031,D_032,D_033,D_028,D_029,D_030,D_025,D_026,D_027,D_022,D_023,D_024,D_019,D_020,D_021,D_016,D_017,D_018,D_013,D_014,D_015,D_010,D_011,D_012,D_007,D_008,D_009,D_004,D_005,D_006,D_001,D_002,D_003,PROTOKOLLNR,GERAETENR,PRUEFER,UEBERTRAGUNGSDATEN,ID_GERAET2,ID_GERAET3,ID_GERAET4,GERAETENR2,GERAETENR3,GERAETENR4,Bemerkungen,Durchgefuehrte_Arbeiten,ID_Techniker) VALUES(:ZEITSTEMPEL,:ID_MESSPROTOKOLL,:ID_GERAET,:D_229,:D_230,:TYP,:D_226,:D_227,:D_228,:D_223,:D_224,:D_225,:D_220,:D_221,:D_222,:D_217,:D_218,:D_219,:D_214,:D_215,:D_216,:D_211,:D_212,:D_213,:D_208,:D_209,:D_210,:D_205,:D_206,:D_207,:D_202,:D_203,:D_204,:D_199,:D_200,:D_201,:D_196,:D_197,:D_198,:D_193,:D_194,:D_195,:D_190,:D_191,:D_192,:D_187,:D_188,:D_189,:D_184,:D_185,:D_186,:D_181,:D_182,:D_183,:D_178,:D_179,:D_180,:D_175,:D_176,:D_177,:D_172,:D_173,:D_174,:D_169,:D_170,:D_171,:D_166,:D_167,:D_168,:D_163,:D_164,:D_165,:D_160,:D_161,:D_162,:D_157,:D_158,:D_159,:D_154,:D_155,:D_156,:D_151,:D_152,:D_153,:D_148,:D_149,:D_150,:D_145,:D_146,:D_147,:D_142,:D_143,:D_144,:D_139,:D_140,:D_141,:D_136,:D_137,:D_138,:D_133,:D_134,:D_135,:D_130,:D_131,:D_132,:D_127,:D_128,:D_129,:D_124,:D_125,:D_126,:D_121,:D_122,:D_123,:D_118,:D_119,:D_120,:D_115,:D_116,:D_117,:D_112,:D_113,:D_114,:D_109,:D_110,:D_111,:D_106,:D_107,:D_108,:D_103,:D_104,:D_105,:D_100,:D_101,:D_102,:D_097,:D_098,:D_099,:D_094,:D_095,:D_096,:D_091,:D_092,:D_093,:D_088,:D_089,:D_090,:D_085,:D_086,:D_087,:D_082,:D_083,:D_084,:D_079,:D_080,:D_081,:D_076,:D_077,:D_078,:D_073,:D_074,:D_075,:D_070,:D_071,:D_072,:D_067,:D_068,:D_069,:D_064,:D_065,:D_066,:D_061,:D_062,:D_063,:D_058,:D_059,:D_060,:D_055,:D_056,:D_057,:D_052,:D_053,:D_054,:D_049,:D_050,:D_051,:D_046,:D_047,:D_048,:D_043,:D_044,:D_045,:D_040,:D_041,:D_042,:D_037,:D_038,:D_039,:D_034,:D_035,:D_036,:D_031,:D_032,:D_033,:D_028,:D_029,:D_030,:D_025,:D_026,:D_027,:D_022,:D_023,:D_024,:D_019,:D_020,:D_021,:D_016,:D_017,:D_018,:D_013,:D_014,:D_015,:D_010,:D_011,:D_012,:D_007,:D_008,:D_009,:D_004,:D_005,:D_006,:D_001,:D_002,:D_003,:PROTOKOLLNR,:GERAETENR,:PRUEFER,:UEBERTRAGUNGSDATEN,:ID_GERAET2,:ID_GERAET3,:ID_GERAET4,:GERAETENR2,:GERAETENR3,:GERAETENR4,:Bemerkungen,:Durchgefuehrte_Arbeiten,:ID_Techniker)";
        try {
            $db = DB::getInstance();
            $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ZEITSTEMPEL', $ZEITSTEMPEL); //this is also null??
            $stmt->bindParam(':ID_MESSPROTOKOLL', $ID_MESSPROTOKOLL);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ID_GERAET', $ID_GERAET);
            //continues...
            $stmt->execute();
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            $db = null;
            $json = '{"count":{'.json_encode($count).'}}';
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
        }
        return $json;
    }
}
```

If you need example JSON plz tell me.

Any idea? Thx
Inge

Comment: Fixed firefox problem (JSON needs to be lowercase json)... using CURL all runs ok but with rest api explorer json will not be available in post function :( Is there a limitation for parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Restler handles converting php array or object t JSON, XML etc. So do not json_encode yourself. Just return the result

You should be returning something like

```
return array('count'=>$count);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i'll change it. But this doesn't solve my problem. I can't get the params from request body. Any ideas? Thanks so far

Answer (score 0):

query string obviously has a limitation on the total length, but body parameter does not have such contraints

I have tested the following with Restler and API Explorer, it just works fine. Make sure you have the latest version of Restler (from master branch) and latest version of API Explorer

```
<?php


class messprotokoll
{

    /**
     * save messprotokoll
     *
     * one could save a messprotokoll
     * result is the status
     *
     *
     * @param string $ZEITSTEMPEL      {@from body} comment
     * @param string $ID_MESSPROTOKOLL {@from body} comment
     * @param string $ID_GERAET        {@from body} comment
     * @param string $D_229            {@from body} comment
     * @param string $D_230            {@from body} comment
     * @param string $TYP              {@from body} comment
     * ....continues...
     *
     * @throws 400 No value given for id
     * @return array
     *
     */
    function post($ZEITSTEMPEL = NULL, $ID_MESSPROTOKOLL = NULL, $ID_GERAET = NULL, $D_229 = NULL, $D_230 = NULL, $TYP = NULL, $D_226 = NULL, $D_227 = NULL, $D_228 = NULL, $D_223 = NULL, $D_224 = NULL, $D_225 = NULL, $D_220 = NULL, $D_221 = NULL, $D_222 = NULL, $D_217 = NULL, $D_218 = NULL, $D_219 = NULL, $D_214 = NULL, $D_215 = NULL, $D_216 = NULL, $D_211 = NULL, $D_212 = NULL, $D_213 = NULL, $D_208 = NULL, $D_209 = NULL, $D_210 = NULL, $D_205 = NULL, $D_206 = NULL, $D_207 = NULL, $D_202 = NULL, $D_203 = NULL, $D_204 = NULL, $D_199 = NULL, $D_200 = NULL, $D_201 = NULL, $D_196 = NULL, $D_197 = NULL, $D_198 = NULL, $D_193 = NULL, $D_194 = NULL, $D_195 = NULL, $D_190 = NULL, $D_191 = NULL, $D_192 = NULL, $D_187 = NULL, $D_188 = NULL, $D_189 = NULL, $D_184 = NULL, $D_185 = NULL, $D_186 = NULL, $D_181 = NULL, $D_182 = NULL, $D_183 = NULL, $D_178 = NULL, $D_179 = NULL, $D_180 = NULL, $D_175 = NULL, $D_176 = NULL, $D_177 = NULL, $D_172 = NULL, $D_173 = NULL, $D_174 = NULL, $D_169 = NULL, $D_170 = NULL, $D_171 = NULL, $D_166 = NULL, $D_167 = NULL, $D_168 = NULL, $D_163 = NULL, $D_164 = NULL, $D_165 = NULL, $D_160 = NULL, $D_161 = NULL, $D_162 = NULL, $D_157 = NULL, $D_158 = NULL, $D_159 = NULL, $D_154 = NULL, $D_155 = NULL, $D_156 = NULL, $D_151 = NULL, $D_152 = NULL, $D_153 = NULL, $D_148 = NULL, $D_149 = NULL, $D_150 = NULL, $D_145 = NULL, $D_146 = NULL, $D_147 = NULL, $D_142 = NULL, $D_143 = NULL, $D_144 = NULL, $D_139 = NULL, $D_140 = NULL, $D_141 = NULL, $D_136 = NULL, $D_137 = NULL, $D_138 = NULL, $D_133 = NULL, $D_134 = NULL, $D_135 = NULL, $D_130 = NULL, $D_131 = NULL, $D_132 = NULL, $D_127 = NULL, $D_128 = NULL, $D_129 = NULL, $D_124 = NULL, $D_125 = NULL, $D_126 = NULL, $D_121 = NULL, $D_122 = NULL, $D_123 = NULL, $D_118 = NULL, $D_119 = NULL, $D_120 = NULL, $D_115 = NULL, $D_116 = NULL, $D_117 = NULL, $D_112 = NULL, $D_113 = NULL, $D_114 = NULL, $D_109 = NULL, $D_110 = NULL, $D_111 = NULL, $D_106 = NULL, $D_107 = NULL, $D_108 = NULL, $D_103 = NULL, $D_104 = NULL, $D_105 = NULL, $D_100 = NULL, $D_101 = NULL, $D_102 = NULL, $D_097 = NULL, $D_098 = NULL, $D_099 = NULL, $D_094 = NULL, $D_095 = NULL, $D_096 = NULL, $D_091 = NULL, $D_092 = NULL, $D_093 = NULL, $D_088 = NULL, $D_089 = NULL, $D_090 = NULL, $D_085 = NULL, $D_086 = NULL, $D_087 = NULL, $D_082 = NULL, $D_083 = NULL, $D_084 = NULL, $D_079 = NULL, $D_080 = NULL, $D_081 = NULL, $D_076 = NULL, $D_077 = NULL, $D_078 = NULL, $D_073 = NULL, $D_074 = NULL, $D_075 = NULL, $D_070 = NULL, $D_071 = NULL, $D_072 = NULL, $D_067 = NULL, $D_068 = NULL, $D_069 = NULL, $D_064 = NULL, $D_065 = NULL, $D_066 = NULL, $D_061 = NULL, $D_062 = NULL, $D_063 = NULL, $D_058 = NULL, $D_059 = NULL, $D_060 = NULL, $D_055 = NULL, $D_056 = NULL, $D_057 = NULL, $D_052 = NULL, $D_053 = NULL, $D_054 = NULL, $D_049 = NULL, $D_050 = NULL, $D_051 = NULL, $D_046 = NULL, $D_047 = NULL, $D_048 = NULL, $D_043 = NULL, $D_044 = NULL, $D_045 = NULL, $D_040 = NULL, $D_041 = NULL, $D_042 = NULL, $D_037 = NULL, $D_038 = NULL, $D_039 = NULL, $D_034 = NULL, $D_035 = NULL, $D_036 = NULL, $D_031 = NULL, $D_032 = NULL, $D_033 = NULL, $D_028 = NULL, $D_029 = NULL, $D_030 = NULL, $D_025 = NULL, $D_026 = NULL, $D_027 = NULL, $D_022 = NULL, $D_023 = NULL, $D_024 = NULL, $D_019 = NULL, $D_020 = NULL, $D_021 = NULL, $D_016 = NULL, $D_017 = NULL, $D_018 = NULL, $D_013 = NULL, $D_014 = NULL, $D_015 = NULL, $D_010 = NULL, $D_011 = NULL, $D_012 = NULL, $D_007 = NULL, $D_008 = NULL, $D_009 = NULL, $D_004 = NULL, $D_005 = NULL, $D_006 = NULL, $D_001 = NULL, $D_002 = NULL, $D_003 = NULL, $PROTOKOLLNR = NULL, $GERAETENR = NULL, $PRUEFER = NULL, $UEBERTRAGUNGSDATEN = NULL, $ID_GERAET2 = NULL, $ID_GERAET3 = NULL, $ID_GERAET4 = NULL, $GERAETENR2 = NULL, $GERAETENR3 = NULL, $GERAETENR4 = NULL, $Bemerkungen = NULL, $Durchgefuehrte_Arbeiten = NULL, $ID_Techniker = NULL, $request_data = NULL)
    {

        var_dump($request_data['ZEITSTEMPEL']); //this is NULL??
        $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.MESSPROTOKOLL(ZEITSTEMPEL,ID_MESSPROTOKOLL,ID_GERAET,D_229,D_230,TYP,D_226,D_227,D_228,D_223,D_224,D_225,D_220,D_221,D_222,D_217,D_218,D_219,D_214,D_215,D_216,D_211,D_212,D_213,D_208,D_209,D_210,D_205,D_206,D_207,D_202,D_203,D_204,D_199,D_200,D_201,D_196,D_197,D_198,D_193,D_194,D_195,D_190,D_191,D_192,D_187,D_188,D_189,D_184,D_185,D_186,D_181,D_182,D_183,D_178,D_179,D_180,D_175,D_176,D_177,D_172,D_173,D_174,D_169,D_170,D_171,D_166,D_167,D_168,D_163,D_164,D_165,D_160,D_161,D_162,D_157,D_158,D_159,D_154,D_155,D_156,D_151,D_152,D_153,D_148,D_149,D_150,D_145,D_146,D_147,D_142,D_143,D_144,D_139,D_140,D_141,D_136,D_137,D_138,D_133,D_134,D_135,D_130,D_131,D_132,D_127,D_128,D_129,D_124,D_125,D_126,D_121,D_122,D_123,D_118,D_119,D_120,D_115,D_116,D_117,D_112,D_113,D_114,D_109,D_110,D_111,D_106,D_107,D_108,D_103,D_104,D_105,D_100,D_101,D_102,D_097,D_098,D_099,D_094,D_095,D_096,D_091,D_092,D_093,D_088,D_089,D_090,D_085,D_086,D_087,D_082,D_083,D_084,D_079,D_080,D_081,D_076,D_077,D_078,D_073,D_074,D_075,D_070,D_071,D_072,D_067,D_068,D_069,D_064,D_065,D_066,D_061,D_062,D_063,D_058,D_059,D_060,D_055,D_056,D_057,D_052,D_053,D_054,D_049,D_050,D_051,D_046,D_047,D_048,D_043,D_044,D_045,D_040,D_041,D_042,D_037,D_038,D_039,D_034,D_035,D_036,D_031,D_032,D_033,D_028,D_029,D_030,D_025,D_026,D_027,D_022,D_023,D_024,D_019,D_020,D_021,D_016,D_017,D_018,D_013,D_014,D_015,D_010,D_011,D_012,D_007,D_008,D_009,D_004,D_005,D_006,D_001,D_002,D_003,PROTOKOLLNR,GERAETENR,PRUEFER,UEBERTRAGUNGSDATEN,ID_GERAET2,ID_GERAET3,ID_GERAET4,GERAETENR2,GERAETENR3,GERAETENR4,Bemerkungen,Durchgefuehrte_Arbeiten,ID_Techniker) VALUES(:ZEITSTEMPEL,:ID_MESSPROTOKOLL,:ID_GERAET,:D_229,:D_230,:TYP,:D_226,:D_227,:D_228,:D_223,:D_224,:D_225,:D_220,:D_221,:D_222,:D_217,:D_218,:D_219,:D_214,:D_215,:D_216,:D_211,:D_212,:D_213,:D_208,:D_209,:D_210,:D_205,:D_206,:D_207,:D_202,:D_203,:D_204,:D_199,:D_200,:D_201,:D_196,:D_197,:D_198,:D_193,:D_194,:D_195,:D_190,:D_191,:D_192,:D_187,:D_188,:D_189,:D_184,:D_185,:D_186,:D_181,:D_182,:D_183,:D_178,:D_179,:D_180,:D_175,:D_176,:D_177,:D_172,:D_173,:D_174,:D_169,:D_170,:D_171,:D_166,:D_167,:D_168,:D_163,:D_164,:D_165,:D_160,:D_161,:D_162,:D_157,:D_158,:D_159,:D_154,:D_155,:D_156,:D_151,:D_152,:D_153,:D_148,:D_149,:D_150,:D_145,:D_146,:D_147,:D_142,:D_143,:D_144,:D_139,:D_140,:D_141,:D_136,:D_137,:D_138,:D_133,:D_134,:D_135,:D_130,:D_131,:D_132,:D_127,:D_128,:D_129,:D_124,:D_125,:D_126,:D_121,:D_122,:D_123,:D_118,:D_119,:D_120,:D_115,:D_116,:D_117,:D_112,:D_113,:D_114,:D_109,:D_110,:D_111,:D_106,:D_107,:D_108,:D_103,:D_104,:D_105,:D_100,:D_101,:D_102,:D_097,:D_098,:D_099,:D_094,:D_095,:D_096,:D_091,:D_092,:D_093,:D_088,:D_089,:D_090,:D_085,:D_086,:D_087,:D_082,:D_083,:D_084,:D_079,:D_080,:D_081,:D_076,:D_077,:D_078,:D_073,:D_074,:D_075,:D_070,:D_071,:D_072,:D_067,:D_068,:D_069,:D_064,:D_065,:D_066,:D_061,:D_062,:D_063,:D_058,:D_059,:D_060,:D_055,:D_056,:D_057,:D_052,:D_053,:D_054,:D_049,:D_050,:D_051,:D_046,:D_047,:D_048,:D_043,:D_044,:D_045,:D_040,:D_041,:D_042,:D_037,:D_038,:D_039,:D_034,:D_035,:D_036,:D_031,:D_032,:D_033,:D_028,:D_029,:D_030,:D_025,:D_026,:D_027,:D_022,:D_023,:D_024,:D_019,:D_020,:D_021,:D_016,:D_017,:D_018,:D_013,:D_014,:D_015,:D_010,:D_011,:D_012,:D_007,:D_008,:D_009,:D_004,:D_005,:D_006,:D_001,:D_002,:D_003,:PROTOKOLLNR,:GERAETENR,:PRUEFER,:UEBERTRAGUNGSDATEN,:ID_GERAET2,:ID_GERAET3,:ID_GERAET4,:GERAETENR2,:GERAETENR3,:GERAETENR4,:Bemerkungen,:Durchgefuehrte_Arbeiten,:ID_Techniker)";
        try {
            $db = DB::getInstance();
            $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ZEITSTEMPEL', $ZEITSTEMPEL); //this is also null??
            $stmt->bindParam(':ID_MESSPROTOKOLL', $ID_MESSPROTOKOLL);
            $stmt->bindParam(':ID_GERAET', $ID_GERAET);
            //continues...
            $stmt->execute();
            $count = $stmt->rowCount();
            $db = null;
            $array = array('count' => $count);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw new \Luracast\Restler\RestException(500, $e->getMessage());
        }
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Resulting API Explorer when I tried it along with our documentation example

[image: download and see the image in actual size]